# My array is defined, but my array at a specific index is undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, indexing, undefined

```
function getLinkList() {
    var linkList = [];
    $.getJSON("http://api.teleport.org/api/urban_areas/", function(json) {
        for (var i = 0; i < json['count']; i++) {
            linkList.push(json['_links']['ua:item'][i]['href']);
        }
    });
    return linkList;
}
var x = getLinkList();
console.log(x);
console.log(x[2]);
```

so the first console.log displays my entire array properly, but the second one shows as 'undefined'. This does not make sense to me as x seems to store the array.

Comment: The problem is that `$.getJSON` is asynchronous so, as you'll see in that other question, your array hasn't been populated yet.

Comment: Read about callbacks and async processing...